# How to disable TYPO3 7.6 Cache for extension on page

Tags: php, caching, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I've created a new page and run a FE plugin from an own extension in TYPO3 7.6.22. In the page settings I set cache to off, add `config.no_cache = 1` and `page.config.no_cache = 1` to the template of that page and added all actions of the FE plugin to the non-cachable actions:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    '___vendor___',
    '___pluginname___',
    [
        'Product' => 'onepage, checkout, advice, confirm'
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Product' => 'onepage, checkout, advice, confirm'
    ]
);
```

But still if I changed some lines in the related `ProductController` file I still need to refresh all caches in the install tool. Why is that? How to change?

Additional information 1: I run RealUrl and the plugin still adds cHash to the URL

Additional information 2: There is kind of an minute caching of extension files. Is that right? Can I deactivate that for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks more like APC is the issue which caches the PHP files and not the TYPO3 caches.

Regarding realurl: you need to disable chash generation while generating the links, the chash is also added even though you are using an uncached action because it might be still needed for other plugins on the same page.

Comment: You are right. I deactivated APC for now and it works like charm. My hoster says it's a default feature of a PHP FASTCGI environment. I will reactive that after going back to production mode. Thanks :)